# progress bar for window mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

instead of wait cursor i was trying to put progress bar in my application.

but haven't got success till yet.

got so many solution on internet but all are for windows application, as i work on compact framework most of the events doesn't works on it.

is there any way to use progress bar or any customized progress bar for window mobile app.

which may start in try block and end in final block...

any piece of code or suggestion would be highly appriciable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally got it.... :)

Visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21302/Custom-ProgressBar-for-NET-Compact-Framework

if finding any problem i can help on it....